# Calculating time constant of a less than 50 % duty cycle 555 timer circuit

Tags: diodes, 555, equation

I am building a 555 timer circuit that generates a pulse for my servo motor.
The circuit in mind looks like this:
[image: 555 shorter duty cycle circuit]
I got this circuit from [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555-circuits-part-1.html) site, and it uses a (1N4148) diode, -the same one I intend to use-.
The constant in the time equations for this circuit is 0.8 instead of the ln(2) in the regular astable circuit -without a diode-.

However, this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Shorter_duty_cycle) article states that the constant should be
[image: wikipedia equation]
By looking at the datasheet of my diode (1N4148), I got that forward voltage of my diode is 1 V maximum.
Plugging 1 V in place of Vdiode, (considering my Vcc is 5 V), I get that the constant is 1.25.

Which one is right?

Answer (score 1):

During THigh the capacitor is charging through RA from Vcc/3 to 2Vcc/3

THigh = RA * C * ln ((starting voltage across RA)/(finishing voltage across RA))

THigh = RA * C * ln ((2/3 of Vcc - Vdiode)/(1/3 of Vcc - Vdiode))

Multiply all the factors in the brackets by 3 and you get your second equation.

During TLow the capacitor is discharging through RB from 2Vcc/3 to Vcc/3

TLow is the same equation as for thigh except replace RA with RB.

The voltage, Vdiode will depend on the current flowing through the diodes during the charge and discharge of the capacitor which will depend on the sizes of RA and RB but 0.7V for Vdiode would be a good approximation.

So the above equations give a more accurate result bearing in mind that the 0.7V value for Vdiode is a nominal value. Your first set of equations are more of an approximation - if you plug values of 10V for Vcc and 0.7V for Vdiode into your last equation you will obtain close to that 0.8 multiplier value used in your first set of equations.